# Mongo nodeJS driver, write concerns / acknowledge and error catching

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

The nodeJS mongo driver (version 4.8.0) "insertOne" returns acknowledged + insertedId.
I want to understand if/when acknowledged will be false and a MongoError won't be thrown.

I want to catch and handle mongo errors properly so my code looks something like that:

```js
try {
    const collection = await this.getCollection();

    const result = await collection.insertOne(document);

    if (!result.acknowledged) {
        // What should I throw and how do I know what happened and when it will get  
        // here without an exception thrown
    }

} catch (e) {
    throw e
}
```

And again my question is when will acknowledge be false without throwing an exception / mongoError?

Comment: Found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70192191/what-causes-mongoose-updatemany-to-return-acknowledged-false